# How Can I Transfer The Same File To Multiple Servers With Minimal Bandwidth

Tags: azure, ansible

I am copying the same file to about 50 Azure servers using the [ansible copy task](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html).

```
- copy:
    src: /home/myuser/project/build/fatboot.jar
    dest: /opt/project/fatboot.jar
    owner: foo
    group: foo
    mode: 0644
```

This uploads the same file 50 times to azure (once for each server).

Is it possible to upload it once to azure and then copy it from a remote place to the servers within azure?

Or some other way that reduces the network traffic (and hence time) from my PC?

Answer (score 0):

Place the `.jar` in Blob storage, either [programatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java) or via [az CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload) or by using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) and fetch it from each of the VMs. Then create a [Shared Access Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-generate-sas) for the blob.

This approach should be a few orders of magnitude faster than uploading from your office. All traffic is kept within the same Azure DC, just make sure the storage account is located in the same region with your compute.

```
- name: Fetch jar.jar from blob storage
  get_url:
    url: https://{{storage_account}}.blob.core.windows.net/{{container}}/jar.jar?{{sas_token}}
    dest: /opt/project/jar.jar
    mode: 0644
```

I'm not terribly sure that's how you append a string containing URL query parameters in Ansible, but you get the point.

A [Shared Access Signature URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#examples-of-sas-uris) should look like this when fully formed:

[image: SAS URL breakdown]